# Approximate discrete data by the normal distribution before doing a statistical test assuming continuity?

Tags: t-test, normality-assumption, discrete-data, paired-data

I have n subjects in my experiment, repeating 3 times an action, each time resulting in a success or a failure. These 3 repetitions are IMO not independent because the subject could improve over time. So, I think the binomial distribution cannot apply to my data. (Unless this condition is not that strict?)
I am aggregating over the 3 repetitions for a success rate per action per subject.
Each action belongs to one of the 3 groups A, B and C. Each group doesn't have the same number of actions: 4 in A, 4 in B and 5 in C.

I want to compare if the success rates between the groups of actions are statistically different.

I had tested the normality on the aggregated subdatasets of the pairs of groups and it resulted that each sub-dataset didn't reject the normality hypothesis.

- Would it be correct to approximate the distribution of my originally discrete (0 or 1) data by a normal distribution and therefore use a paired t-test even though one assumption of the t-test is to have continuous data?
- If not, which other test should I use?

Comment: @michael-r-chernick : I edited my question and hope it is now clearer. If not, could you tell me on which points I should be more specific? Thank you in advance

Comment: By editing your post, you have entered it into the community review queue where people will vote on reopening it.  There's no need to flag your post.  Please visit our [help] for more information on how this site works.  I am not voting to reopen because I cannot discern a single clear question here: you mention several issues (dependence, different sample sizes, normality, discreteness, and testing) and ultimately ask a question that makes little sense: there's simply no way a binary response could possibly be approximated by a Normal distribution; they are as unlike as possible.